# Partial Fraction Expansion Methods for inverse z transform

Tags: z-transform

I am following PFE for control system from a book. The author says that first it is best to divide by z for both sides, then multiply back through later. the thing is, that i get a different answer depending on whether or not i follow this.

for example, find inverse z transform for:
$F(z) = \frac{z + 1}{z^{2}+0.3z+0.02}$

method 1
$\frac{F(z)}{z} = \frac{z + 1}{z(z^{2}+0.3z+0.02)}$

$z+1=\frac{A}{z}+\frac{B}{z+0.1}+\frac{C}{z+0.2}$

Coefficients, A = 50, B = -90, C = 40.

PFE: $F(z) = \frac{50z}{z} - \frac{90z}{z+0.1}+\frac{40z}{z+0.2}$

Look up table ANSWER (method 1): $f(n)=50\delta(n)-90(-0.1)^{n}+40(-0.2)^{n}$ for $n\ge0$

method 2
no division by z at the start
$F(z) = \frac{z + 1}{z^{2}+0.3z+0.02}=\frac{A}{z+0.1}+\frac{B}{z+0.2}$

PF coefficients A = 9, B =-8

PFE is $F(z)=\frac{9}{z+0.1}-\frac{8}{z+0.2}$

This can be written as $F(Z)=\frac{9z}{z+0.1}z^{-1}-\frac{8z}{z+0.2}z^{-1} $

ANSWER from look up table (method 2): $f(n)=9(-0.1)^{n-1}-8(-0.2)^{n-1}$ for $n\ge0$

Any help? Am I missing something? Why don't I get the same answer?
The constant $50\delta(n)$ appears to be the main difference

thank u

Comment: im still thinking about this.... should $n \ge 0 or 1$ for method 2? But still... hmmmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: **A better approach for Method #2**

You correctly have $$F(z)= \frac{9}{z+0.1} - \frac{8}{z+0.2}$$
But to use the look up tables (with positive powers of z), you want the fractions to be in the form $\frac{z}{z+a}$, where $a$ is a constant. The essence of the following step is to express $\frac{a}{z+a}$ as $\left(1-\frac{z}{z+a}\right)$.

$$\begin{align} F(z) &= \frac{9}{z+0.1} - \frac{8}{z+0.2} \\
       &= 90 \frac{0.1}{z + 0.1} - 40 \frac{0.2}{z + 0.2} \\
&=90 \left(1 - \frac{z}{z + 0.1}\right) - 40 \left(1 - \frac{z}{z + 0.2}\right) \\ &=90-90\frac{z}{z + 0.1} -40 + 40\frac{z}{z + 0.2} \\
&=50 - 90\frac{z}{z + 0.1}+ 40\frac{z}{z + 0.2}
\end{align}$$

Performing the inverse Z-transform:
$$\mathcal{Z}^{-1} \{F(z)\} = \mathcal{Z}^{-1}\{50\} - \mathcal{Z}^{-1}\{ 90\frac{z}{z + 0.1}  \} + \mathcal{Z}^{-1}\{ 40\frac{z}{z + 0.1}  \}$$

Finally:
$$ f(n)=50\delta(n)-\left[90(-0.1)^n + 40(-0.2)^n\right]u(n) $$

**The previous and longer approach (edited)**

You have
$$F(z)=\frac{9}{z+0.1} - \frac{8}{z+0.2} = \frac{9z}{z+0.1}z^{-1} - \frac{8z}{z+0.2}z^{-1}$$
This implies that
$$zF(z)=\frac{9z}{z+0.1} - \frac{8z}{z+0.2}$$
Taking the inverse $Z$ transform gives:
$$\mathcal{Z}^{-1}\left\{zF(z)\right\}=f(n+1)=\left\{
    \begin{array}{rl}
      9(-0.1)^n - 8(-0.2)^n & \text{if } n \ge 0 \\
      0 & \text{if } n \lt 0
    \end{array} \right. $$

Using the unit step function, $$f(n+1)=[9(-0.1)^n - 8(-0.2)^n]u(n)$$
Using a shift of indices and rewriting, $$\begin{align} f(n)&=\left[9(-0.1)^{(n-1)} - 8(-0.2)^{(n-1)}\right]u(n-1) \\
 &= \left[\frac{9}{-0.1}(-0.1)^n - \frac{8}{-0.2}(-0.2)^n\right]u(n-1)
\end{align}$$

Now, $u(n-1) = u(n) - u(0)=u(n)-\delta(n)$, since $\delta(n)$ is only non-zero when $n = 0$.

This gives:
$$f(n)=\left[-90(-0.1)^n + 40(-0.2)^n\right] {\left[u(n) - \delta(n)\right]}$$

Now, $\left[-90(-0.1)^n + 40(-0.2)^n\right]\delta(n) = -50\delta(n)$, again since $\delta(n)$ is only nonzero when $n = 0$.
Hence, we can rewrite as follows:
$$f(n)=\left[-90(-0.1)^n + 40(-0.2)^n\right] {u(n) + 50\delta(n)}$$

Therefore:
$$f(n)=\left\{
    \begin{array}{rl}
      50\delta(n)-90(-0.1)^n + 40(-0.2)^n & \text{if } n \ge 0 \\
      0 & \text{if } n \lt 0
    \end{array} \right. $$

where $\delta(n) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{rl}
      1 & \text{if } n = 0 \\
      0 & \text{if } n \neq 0
    \end{array} \right. $

Comment: its funny how when you look back over something that you understood years ago.... you no longer understand it!!!
1) I see a typo/error when the inverse z transform is taken. I think it should be "+8" instead of "+4"
2) I cant seem to fathom how the next step, "performing a time shift to get f(n) implies:"
gives -90 instead of -9 and +8- instead of +8. Why the order of mag increase?

Comment: I agree, there were some typos. Corrected and added a better approach.